# What's the difference between Python list comprehension and normal loop?

Tags: python

The next loops returns a value of `3` for `count` parameter:

```
for line in textfile.text.splitlines():
    count += 1 if 'hostname' in line else 0
```

However trying to to do the same using list comprehension returns `1`:

```
count += 1 if ['hostname' in line for line in textfile.text.splitlines()] else 0
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: FYI, it's called list comprehension, not single line loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions are shortcut for list creation. The following is (roughly) equivalent:

```
result = []
for item in l:
    if condition(item):
        result.append(item.attribute)

result = [item.attribute for item in l if condition(item)]
```

So your code

```
count += 1 if ['hostname' in line for line in textfile.text.splitlines()] else 0
```

would be the same as

```
result = []
for line in textfile.text.splitlines():
    result.append('hostname' in line)

count += 1 if result else 0
```

which is obviously not the same as

```
for line in textfile.text.splitlines():
    count += 1 if 'hostname' in line else 0
```

instead you could do things like

```
count += sum([1 for line in textfile.text.splitlines() if 'hostname' in line])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
count += len([line for line in textfile.text.splitlines() if 'hostname' in line])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in second case your if condition is executed only once.

your second statement translates to count += 1 if listobject else 0;

Here the list object is not None so count += 1 is executed once.